# How to set up a Jersey init param?

Tags: glassfish, payara

I need to set up the `jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError` configuration to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Setting Jersey properties in a JAX-RS application is possible by providing an overridden method `getProperties()` in a custom `Application` class, like in [this example in Jersey tests](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/ac34707df4ca97028ce6abfc2eeb4a39eae77b81/tests/integration/ejb-test-webapp/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/tests/ejb/resources/MyApplication.java#L66):

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError", true);
        }};
    }
}
```

The same thing should be possible with an init-param of the Jersey servlet in `web.xml`, like in [this Jersey test app](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/ac34707df4ca97028ce6abfc2eeb4a39eae77b81/tests/integration/servlet-tests/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L50):

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.tests.integration.servlettests</param-value>
        </init-param>
```